# Ordinal or Interval Level of Measurement?

Tags: dataset, measurement, variable

If we have a score of number of students in a kindergarden, which goes "one, two, three, four, five, six and more", is this variable interval or ordinal? The differences between them are exact, yet they are not exact for the last variable, as it can be from 6 to infinity, which may make the data ordinal?

Comment: Some might call this a "right-censored count variable."  That, at least, is unambiguous and precise.  "Ordinal" doesn't capture all the features of this variable and "interval" might be incorrect (unless there are no counts exceeding 6), so you are offering us a false dichotomy.

Comment: Sorry, it's just that we only studied nominal, ordinal, interval and ratio levels of measurement yet, and I was thinking where this type belongs to, as it seems above ordinal but does not have all the features of the interval...

Comment: It's good to reflect on what you have learned.  Many people think that all variables must fall into one of these categories, but that's not the case.  If your objective is to learn more about measurement typology, then you might like to state that in your question.